# Multiple Files Reading in the Promise.all is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, promise

I'm trying to perform some file reading operations as:

1. Reading an Excel file in a Promise containing users' info. After
   resolving that promise, I would have an Array of User.
2. In the then callback of first file reading Promise, Reading face
   image files of users in a Promise with Promise.all.
3. The reason to use Promise.all is, I want async files reading. For
   each image file, I'm looping the whole users array to find the user
   of face image and then store the Base64String result of face to that
   user object. And then resolve Promise with that modified user.
4. As per my understading, if none of the Promises rejected. I should
   have an array of Users in the then callback of Promise.all, that is
   what I want!

But the problem is, with this code Promise.all is neither rejected nor resolved. And with few modifications, It got resolved before all the passed individual promises start resolving.

Here is the code of functions performing files reading.

```
import { User } from "./types";
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";


// Loading users data from Excel Data... Id,Name,CardNo
export async function loadUsersData(usersFile: File) {
  let result_users: User[] =await new Promise((resolve) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      const data = e.target.result;
      const readedData = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
      const wsname = readedData.SheetNames[0];
      const ws = readedData.Sheets[wsname];

      /* Convert array to json*/
      const parsedData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1, blankrows: false });
      parsedData.shift();
      const users: User[] = parsedData.map((item: any) => {
        const id = item[0].toString().trim();
        const name = item[1].toString().trim();
        const cardNo = item[2].toString().trim();
        const user: User = { id, name, cardNo }; 
        return user;
      });

      resolve(users);
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(usersFile)

  });

  return result_users;
}


//Loading Images of Users Faces to display in material table along with other user info
export async function loadUsersFaces(users: User[], facesList: FileList) {
  const facesArray = Array.from(facesList)
  const promises=facesArray.map(async face=>{
    return await readFace(face, users);
  })
  let result_users: any=await Promise.all(promises);
  return result_users
}

function readFace(face: File,users:User[]) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      let faceBase64String = e.target.result; //getting Base64String of image to render as custom column in material-table as https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/custom-column-rendering
      users.map(user => {
        if (face.name.includes(user.id) && face.name.includes(user.name)) {
          let newUser={ ...user, face: faceBase64String };
          console.log(`Resoling ${JSON.stringify(newUser)}`);
          resolve(newUser);
        }
      })
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(face)
  });
}
```

And here is the code of Actions performing files reading one after the other.

```
//Here is usersFile is an excel file Blob and FileList contain list of image files
export const loadUsers = (usersFile: File,faces: FileList) => (dispatch:Dispatch) => {
  dispatch(actions.startCall({ callType: callTypes.list }));
  usersService.loadUsersData(usersFile).then((users:any)=>{ // So far so good till this point.
    usersService.loadUsersFaces(users,faces).then((users:any)=>{
      console.log(users); // Here I should have users including Base64 Strings of face images in face property of User in the whole array of users 
      dispatch(actions.usersFetched({ totalCount:users.length, entities:users }));
    })
  })
};
```

Comment: You don't seem to be handling `error` in `readFace()`, therefore if there **IS** an `error`, `Promise.all()` will never resolve and return a result

Comment: Sounds Good! But in that case that individual Promise would be rejected? As per my debugging, all individual promises are successfully resolved

Comment: As long as 1 `promise` fails, the `Promise.all` operation completes with `error`. Otherwise, you can use `Promise.allSettled`, if you don't care if any `promise` fails.

Comment: I know that but not getting what's going going wrong at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not properly handling errors from the filereaders, not handling errors from the code inside the asynchronous `onload` callbacks, and most importantly you are only conditionally resolving the promise (from a loop!) in the `readFace` function.

Instead, you should refactor that into a separate function for the promisification of the filereader:

```
function readFile(file, method = 'readAsArrayBuffer') {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => resolve(e.target.result);
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader[method](file);
  });
}
```

Now you can write the rest of the code without using `new Promise`:

```
export async function loadUsersData(usersFile: File) {
  const data = await readFile(usersFile, 'readAsBinaryString');
  const readedData = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
  const wsname = readedData.SheetNames[0];
  const ws = readedData.Sheets[wsname];

  /* Convert array to json*/
  const parsedData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1, blankrows: false });
  parsedData.shift();
  const users: User[] = parsedData.map((item: any) => {
    const id = item[0].toString().trim();
    const name = item[1].toString().trim();
    const cardNo = item[2].toString().trim();
    const user: User = { id, name, cardNo }; 
    return user;
  });
  return users;
}

async function readFace(face: File,users:User[]) {
  const faceBase64String = await readFile(face, 'readAsDataURL');
  for (const user of users) {
    if (face.name.includes(user.id) && face.name.includes(user.name)) {
      user.face = faceBase64String;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @DevLoverUmar: Please accept the answer if solved your problem, thank you.

Comment: @DevLoverUmar What exactly is happening? No, `loadUsersFaces` should not need modification.